# To override the key event listener in YUI2 carousel

Tags: javascript, yui, carousel, yui2

I'm using YUI 2 carousel. I want to override the "keydown" event listener with my own event listener.  If I give:

```
node.on('keydown', function(e){ alert("something"); });
```

at first the default event listener defined in carousel-min.js is executed and then my listener is executed. Is there any way to override this default execution completely in yui carousel?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` to override the default behavior:

```
function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert("something"); });
```